# Bivariate Cointegration Test using Johansen Test

Tags: cointegration

I am currently working on my final thesis on the subject of pairs trading and have to carry out a large number of cointegration tests. The reason for this is that I want to compare 100 foreign shares with about 500 shares of the S&P 500, and this over a period of 10 years, rolling every month. This adds up to a seven-digit number and thus an enormous runtime of my code if I design the whole topic in a bivariate way with the help of Engle-Granger test. I have now taken a closer look at Johansen approach, but I can't figure out whether I can test several time series for cointegration at the same time and still get the pairwise connection.

My question now is whether I can pack the time series of share A together with the time series of shares B, C and D into a VAR model, test this model for cointegration with Johansen and still get the respective cointegrations between A-B, A-C, A-D?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you explain more clearly why it's so computationally demanding ? How many pairs of stocks are you considering ? Note that, if you're considering only  pairs, then you're better off using the EG method because using Johansen's methodology will be like killing a fly with a grenade. Iit also  won't help from a computational standpoint.

Comment: i am comparing 100 german stocks with 500 US-Stocks. So that adds up to 50.000 possible cointegration combination per period. I am backtesting the cointegration relationship of the past 12 Months over 10 years with a monthly rolling window. That's 120 periods. That adds up to approx 6 Million tests (assumed all time series are non-stationary which they mostly are). Plus, if I wanna work preciesly, i should check the pairs the other way around. At least considering the last point, Johansen-test would speed up the computations, right?!

Comment: Hi: Pairs trading research has a lot of pieces but here are three comments based on your latest response. 1) I wouldn't use a month. It's going to cause a lot of instability in your results. The cointegration results from one month are going to indicate one thing and then the next month, they'll indicate the opposite. Using a longer time frame.  2) You might want to use some filter for deciding what to compare against what. For example, stocks in same industry. To do a brute force comparison of every stock is not a good idea. 3) I'm still not clear on how johansen would speed up the process ?